# Declaring String variable in C++

Tags: c++, gcc4.9

I use Dev-C++ which has GCC 4.9.2 C++ compiler.
I am confused on where and where not to use the following for declaring a string variable:

1. `#include <string>` only
2. `#include <string.h>` only
3. using `std::string` only and no headers
4. `#include <cstring.h>`

because everything compiles and run in devc++, I am unable to understand the concept behind all these

Comment: `std::string`: _"Defined in header <string>"_  see:   http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string   Also headers:  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header

Answer (score 2):

To use `std::string` always use `#include <string>`.

The other header files you mentioned have nothing to do with `std::string`.

The `std` namespace scope can be omitted if you have an appropriate `using` statement like

```
using std::string;
```

or

```
using namespace std;
```

(the latter [isn't recommended in real code for various reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice))